# ActivePerl - how to move modules to another installation?

Tags: perl, package-managers, activeperl, activestate

we have two servers (Windows Server 2003 and 2008R2) and it is required of us to move the ActivePerl installation from one to the other. Now I have been successful in installing it and it runs good, but now I see that two additional custom modules have been installed on the old server. Is there a way to export them and import on the other machine using ppm.exe for example?

Right now this is the first time that I deal with Perl and I only know the names of the additional modules, nothing else. Also the machines are not exposed to the internet. We are using ActivePerl 5.10.0.

Thank you for any tips on how to migrate the modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same versions of perl you should be able to just copy the modules you want from the libs folder to the other machine.

Comment: One is version 5.10.0 build 1004 and the other is 5.10.0 build 1006. Do you think that still counts as the same version?

Comment: It will most likely work I've done it with 5.6 to 5.10 but it still depends on the actual module.

Comment: If this helped you and it works accept the answer so it's closed :).